How to download all files from Web directory (URL) by POWERSHELL Script?
I have a web directory and I required to download all folder, sub-folders, files as per directory as it is. The directory domain is like https://subDom.mainDom.com:4434/subFolder/ and their are many more sub folder in their and also huge files. I am using a powerShell script which is working fine for the url: https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/observations_germany/climate/daily/kl/recent/ but not for my URL. The code is given below:
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$outputdir = 'C:\temp'
$url       = 'https://subDom.mainDom.com:4434/subFolder/'

# enable TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.1 protocols
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
# get the list of links, skip the first one ("../") and download the files
$WebResponse.Links | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Downloading file '$_'"
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $outputdir -ChildPath $_
    $fileUrl  = '{0}/{1}' -f $url.TrimEnd('/'), $_
    
    
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $filePath
}

Its shows an error for my url:

How to solve the issues? What change needed for the shared powershell code?

Sounds like one or more paths have a square bracket or similar that is being interpreted as a wildcard. Maybe try ”’$filepath’”

?C=D;O=A is not a valid file path - perhaps you'll want to generate the file names instead of try to infer them from the URI?

Oh! I made a mistake on $URL link, I forgot to give last backSlash after the URL. I have given the $url       = 'https://subDom.mainDom.com:4434/subFolder', but It will be $url       = ["https: //subDom.mainDom.com:4434/ subFolder/"] [backslash after url]; OK, now come to the point, after giving the blackslash- If this folder has direct file, then it will download nicely. but if the given url folder has multiple sub-folder under this and then file is stored the individual folder, then what have I need to modify on the code?
